# flutter Gradle task

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I transfer my flutter project to new machine but this error don't let me run the app :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find builder-3.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.3.0/builder-3.3.0.jar
```

I delete my .gralde/cache file but it didn't work for me

here is my build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Probably your current gradle binary version not matching with your build.gradle plugin. Try upgrading your build gradle version to 4.1.0, something like this:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'`

See https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

Comment: still get that error

Comment: try removing gradle binary in .gradle/wrapper/dists/. Usually, the problem is happened because of corrupted gradle binary. And make sure you have restarted your IDE and kill all java processes.

Comment: thank's alot now it works fine

Comment: Great!, try to create your own answer and mark it as an accepted answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after remove gradle binary in .gradle/wrapper/dists/. I was able to run my app and now It works fine .